# Workflow platform for managing the processing of incoming files

Tags: workflow, airflow, cadence-workflow

In general, I have a single workflow that I want to be able to monitor. The workflow should start whenever new files arrive or alternatively at certain scheduled times, i.e. I want to be able to insert new "jobs" to the workflow as they come, and process the files by going through multiple different tasks and steps. I want to be able to monitor each file going through the tasks.
The queues and distributing the load for each task might be managed by Celery, but it's not decided yet either.

I've looked at Apache Airflow, and as far as I understand at the moment,  is geared more towards monitoring many different workflows, such that each workflow is mostly running from start to end, not adding new files to the beginning of the flow before the previous run ended.
Cadence workflow seems like can do what I need, but also seems to be a bit of an overkill.

I'm not expecting a specific final solution here, but I would appreciate suggestions to more such solutions that I can look into and can fit the above.

Comment: Why do you think Cadence Workflow is overkill? The coding is simpler and service is not hard to run.

Answer (score 0):

Luigi - https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Extremely light-weight and fast compared to Airflow.